# Non Exhaustive Pattern Matching? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

For some reason, when I run the code with for exmaple let's say split1 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] I get an error

```
p :: Int -> Bool
p x  = if x < 5 then True else False

split1 [xs] = [([x,y]) | x <- [xs], y <- [xs], p x == True, p y == False]
```

Even if I run it with split1 [1] I get an empty set. Can someone tell me where i'm wrong? Thanks.

Comment: As a style note, I'd avoid `p x = if x<5 then True else False`, and simply use the simpler equivalent `p x = x<5`. Similarly, `p x == True` is equivalent to `p x`, and `p y == False` is equivalent to `not (p y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
split1 [xs] = ...
```

You're essentially doing a pattern matching on first argument. `[xs]` is pattern for a list with only one element. What you need instead is this:

```
split1 xs = [([x,y]) | x <- xs, y <- xs, p x == True, p y == False]
```

Note that I removed list brackets around xs in the definition too.

I don't know what you're trying to do, but you may want to get rid of list brackets in `([x,y])` too.

```
split1 xs = [(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- xs, p x == True, p y == False]
```